# solution for text aligning inconsistency with label and long span text

Tags: html, css

Within a "li" tag I have 2 subtags: 1 "label" and "span".

```
<li>
  <label ...>labelname</label>
  <span>span value</span>
</li>
```

The problem that I have is, when the text in the span gets pretty long, there is a linebreak and the span text gets to side of the label.

```
labeltext:           Here comes the very very long text of the span and
after the linebreak the text gets to the side of the label.
```

It should be like this

```
labeltext:           Here comes the very very long text of the span and     
                     after the linebreak the text gets to the side of the...
```

I know that one solution to this can be the insertion of another container.

```
<li>
  <span style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;">
    <label>labelname</label>
  </span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; width: 70%;">
    <span>span value</span>
  </span>
</li>
```

My question is, if there is a solution WITHOUT the insertion of extra containers, just by adding a few css-attributes to the tags.

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is inline-block but without wrapping new elements, as your request:

```css
label, span { display: inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
label {width: 25%;}
span {width:74%; }
```

```html
<li>
  <label>labelname</label>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu lacinia risus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In egestas metus turpis, vel placerat magna pretium sed. Morbi rhoncus vehicula est, ac dapibus magna aliquam eget. Duis viverra posuere pretium. Donec eget fringilla eros. Etiam ut enim quis dui mattis consectetur. Integer dui dui, hendrerit ut vestibulum ac, aliquam vitae turpis. </span>
</li>
```

Comment: This solution is not good. You fill 99% of the space here so if you go 100% it breaks. What you need is float: left on both elements then it will work. Browsers add by default a little gap on inline-block elements so this is why in your case 100% on the whole container (li) would be more than 100%. Thats why you want to use float.

Comment: I can make 100% with the two elements making hide the whitespaces. It's simply, `li { font-size:0 } label,span {font-size:1rem; }` And you don't have to write floats. Floats is for float elements, not for layouts

Comment: I did some reasearch on this and I found out that there are many ways to do this actually. All those solutions are just kinda weird in my opinion cause why would you set a font-size to 0? Sounds super hacky. Also you have more rules to care about. You will get business designs in px and pt not in rem. Float is easy and browser friendly. All you have to do is to apply the clear on the :after-pseudo element. Well anyways, in the end all that counts is if it does work or not. Please at this code (font-size) to your solution. Because otherwhise it does break.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like the `display: flex;` style property. If you add the vendor prefixes browser support is pretty good this days.

```css
li {
  display: flex;
}
li * { /* just for visible separation */
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <label>labelname</label>
  <span>span valueaasdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf span valueaasdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdf</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add float:left to your inline css for both span.

```html
<li>
  <span style="display: inline-block; width: 30%; float:left">
    <label>labelname</label>
  </span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; width: 70%; float:left">
    <span>span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value span value </span>
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Why do you mix `inline-block` with `float`? These two properties are antagonists.

Comment: Thank you for your posting. But my question was if there is a solution WITHOUT the insertion of a new container to the original setting (just "li", "label" and "span".